# Google sheets ifs then else problem

Tags: google-sheets

Using Google Sheets.

I would like to change to use several conditions which results different values, and if nothing else did not match, then result other value.

In pseudo code:

```
A1 = 8
Set B1 If A1=1, then B1 result is 100,
If A1=4, then B1 result is 200,
If A1=6, then B1 result is 300,
If A1=10, then B1 result is 400,
Else B1 result is 0.
```

What formula is the most simplest way to describe this?

Answer (score 8):

Off the top of my head, this should do what you're looking for.

```
=IF(A1=1,100,IF(A1=4,200,IF(A1=6,300,IF(A1=10,400,0))))
```

Broken down into pseudo code:

```
IF 
  A1=1
THEN
  100
ELSE
  IF 
    A1=4
  THEN
    200
  ELSE
    IF
      A1=6
    THEN
      300
    ELSE
      IF
        A1=10
      THEN
        400
      ELSE
        0
```

To do it with IFS, this should do:

```
=IFS(A1=1, 100, A1=4, 200, A1=6, 300, A1=10, 400, true, 0)
```

SWITCH would be this:

```
=SWITCH(A1, 1, 100, 4, 200, 6, 300, 10, 400, 0)
```

---

Google Sheets functions:

- [IF()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [IFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [SWITCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690)